# How to append string values inside if condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am new to XSL.I have an XML as below, If CoverageCode equals -'HomeCoverage' then I have to verify for the next 3 elements of 'roofRestrictionEndt','sidingRestrictionEndt'and 'paintRestrictionEndt' . If 'roofRestrictionEndt' exits and its value is 'Y' then I need to print 'Roof' under the 'results' tag, If  'sidingRestrictionEndt' exists and its value is 'Y' then I need to print 'siding' in case if it exists along with the above one then I need to print 'Roof; siding'. If 'paintRestrictionEndt' exists and its value is 'Y' along with the other 2 elements then I need to print 'Roof; siding; paint'.  I tried by declaring variables and wrote If conditions and tried to append values accordingly inside IF condition, but I came to know the declared variables are immutable. In java, we can achieve this by using StringBuffer. Is there any way to achieve this in XSL? Below is XML.

```
<locationCoverage ID="3">

<coverageCode >HomeCoverage</coverageCode>
<roofRestrictionEndt >Y</roofRestrictionEndt>
      <sidingRestrictionEndt>Y</sidingRestrictionEndt>
      <paintRestrictionEndt >Y</paintRestrictionEndt>
<locationCoverage>
```

Results should look like as below

```
<results>
      <result>Roof;siding;paint</result>
      
      </results>
```

If I have below input XML

```
<locationCoverage ID="3">
<coverageCode >HomeCoverage</coverageCode>
<roofRestrictionEndt >Y</roofRestrictionEndt>
 <paintRestrictionEndt >Y</paintRestrictionEndt>
</locationCoverage>
```

For the above XML results should look like as below

```
<results>
      <result>Roof;paint</result>
      
      </results>
```

Appreciate it If anyone helps me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly (which is not at all certain), you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="locationCoverage[coverageCode='HomeCoverage']">
    <xsl:variable name="test-results">
        <xsl:if test="roofRestrictionEndt='Y'">Roof </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="sidingRestrictionEndt='Y'">siding </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="paintRestrictionEndt='Y'">paint</xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space($test-results), ' ', ';')"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```